# How to delete a speed dial in Asterisk/FreePBX

Tags: asterisk, freepbx

Using FreePBX 15. This is a test system for evaluating the possible use of
FreePBX in our university environment.

From a phone, I used the Asterisk star code *75 to enter a speed dial.
Now I want to delete that. I cannot find any way to do it.
Asterisk doesn't provide a cancellation code.
I checked the Asterisk Phonebook, and my entry is not there, yet
it is still active when I dial the speed code from a phone.

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: I had already posted on the freepbx community forum, but haven't yet received a response. I just tried what you suggested. 'database show' showed the 2 entries I made. I executed the del command on them. But they did not
delete! And the speed dials still work when I try them in the phone... Is there anything else I can try? If I could locate the database and if
the entries are text or other editable form, I can manually delete them...but I'm not familiar with sqlite..

Comment: Phil, it looks like you've accidentally created a second account. Please see https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts so that you can take ownership of this question. Thank you!

Comment: mikem, Emergency cancelled! I made a mistake in my syntax. The entries are gone! Thanks very much for your help.. Phil

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure you used the asterisk *75 to store the speed dial and didn't store it directly in the phone, then try this on your asterisk server:

Enter the asterisk command CLI (asterisk -r)

```
CLI> database show AMPUSER/205/speeddials
```

(Where 205 is the extension/user number)

It should return something like:

```
AMPUSER/205/speeddials/15555551212
```

(where in this example 15555551212 is the speed dial number you no longer want)

I'm not sure of the exact syntax it will return off hand, but it should be pretty obvious.

Once you find the one you're looking for, try:

```
CLI> database del AMPUSER/205/speeddials 15555551212
```

I think there is a FreePBX module called "Speed Dial Functions" that might help with this, but I've never used it so you'll have to try it on your own.

Also note, FreePBX has their own forums that you might find more useful (https://community.freepbx.org/).